# Stop Outlook from loading Image from internal IP

Tags: microsoft-outlook, blocking, email-signature

We removed old IP range from our internal network.
For example `10.1.30.1/16`

Our clients are in `10.2.10.0/24` now. Server are in another `/24` vlan

Signatures in Outlook have HTML code, loading image from a network share. This used to point to `10.1.30.1`. Now this IP is not reachable anymore.

If I open an old email, Outlook takes a long time, while displaying

> "contacting the server for information"

[image: Popup]

(sample in English, I have German system)

Can I stop Outlook from trying to fetch images from this old, not existing IP? Do I need to set up Firewall rules, prohibiting outgoing connections to this IP?

Addding the IP `10.1.30.1` to Junk E-Mail Options - blocked senders does NOT help

Comment: Check this link and see if it helps: https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/outlook_com/forum/all/how-to-turn-off-automatic-image-downloads-for/ae637b7f-2a41-42e2-a30c-822e87b6429a

Comment: Thx. But the IP is part of the internal network and domain. So it will not help until the IP range is gone for good any maybe not even then